# Django fetch related child with parent object

Tags: django, django-models, django-select-related, django-related-manager

I am using Django 2.2 and I have a model with two classes `Product` and `ProductRevision`. When I retrieve a `Product`, or a list of `Product`s, I always fetch the corresponding `ProductRevision`. `ProductRevision` objects are incremented and only the last revision should be fetched with the `Product`.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False,
                            verbose_name=_("name"))
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False,
                                    verbose_name=_("product code"))
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)

    @property
    def current_item(self):
        return ProductRevision.objects.filter(product=self, active=True).order_by('-version').first()


class ProductRevision(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                  verbose_name=_("version"))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name=_("is active"))
    qty_close = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                    verbose_name=_("qty of accounts to be closed"))
    price_eur = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0,
                                    verbose_name=_("price in EUR"))
```

I tried to add a property `current_item` to get the last revision of a given product. While this is working, it is very inefficient because when I use it in a template, it hits the database every time I display a field from the related `ProductRevision`.

I found this answer based on an old version of Django ([Fetch latest related objects in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249830/fetch-latest-related-objects-in-django)) and I'm wondering if there is no other ways to achieve the same result with current versions of Django? I'm particularly interrested in achieving this in my models.

Comment: Are you using postgres?

Comment: Yes, postgres 11.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to achieve something similar to this by using a [custom prefetch related queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'productrevision_set',
    queryset=ProductRevision.objects.order_by('product', '-version').distinct('product'),
    to_attr='latest_revision'
))
```

The queryset above will only return one `ProductRevision` per `Product` which in effect gives us the latest `ProductRevision` for all `Products` in only 2 queries

```
for product in products:
    for latest_revision in product.latest_revision:
        print(product, latest_revision)
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the way to go! You should replace **product** with **product_id** in the queryset: `queryset=ProductRevision.objects.order_by('product_id', '-version').distinct('product')` otherwise you get the **SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions** error (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582966/django-order-by-filter-with-distinct for more information)